# Bootloop problem. Lenovo A600e

Tags: stock-android, lenovo

I have this cellphone for my CDMA card and also it is my fav cell phone as gifted from my first girlfriend. It went in bootloop. However I got the flash zip file on internet. But couldn't find the better tool to flash this zip. If I want to flash via android recovery then external SD card is not getting in that. From which I could flash that zip. I want this cell phone back to work. Least ABD tricks may you know guys? Pls help me.

PS : our english teacher got hit by bus.

Answer (score 0):

Flash your phone using a computer. As your phone is powered by Mediatek chips, it is easy to flash.

Go *[here](https://androidmtk.com/download-lenovo-stock-rom-models)* and download the firmware for your phone model and *[here](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool)* for Instructions.

Comment: I have searched more than 19 pages of google engine but I could not find above models stock ROM. I have a T-update zip file. Which can be flash with android recovery. While I entered in recovery i found the suspect that emmc failed something. Also I could not find my External SD card which I have T-zip in that. Do you know how to push n pull file using cmd in bootloop android?